# JQuery Ajax $_GET request received an incorrect response from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, ajaxform

Something wrong going on:

I am sending data to php through an ajax request. There it checked that received an empty or non-empty GET and for each of these options it return different answers. The problem is that on the php page the answer is correct, but it becomes incorrect when it returns to the page from which it was sent.

***When GET is empty, php returns 'empty' (as expected), but ajax prints 'not empty' (expected 'empty')***

I absolutely do not understand why this is happening. I tried returning various with both exit and return

AJAX:

```js
$(".rate_form .submit").click(function() {
  var rate_form = $(this).parents().find('.rate_form');
  var rate = rate_form.serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "rate.php",
    data: {
      "rate": rate
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

RATE.PHP:

```php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if(empty($_GET)){
    exit('empty');
}elseif (!empty($_GET)){
    exit('not empty');
}
```

---

---

### **UPD: I tried @Barmar suggestion**

Unfortunately, this is not related to the problem. I completely got rid of "cache", but the situation has not changed. I even tried checking only one $ _GET argument for `empty()` (trying `isset()` also).

**The result is the same as before:** in rate.php the answer is correct (depending on whether the request is empty or with arguments), and on the page with the form there is always only one answer: "empty". Moreover, even stranger, if you return the $ _GET array, then it returns correctly (when $ _GET is not empty, it returns "empty" and **not empty** array)

```php
if (!empty($_GET['rating'])){
    print_r($_GET);
    exit('not empty');
} else {
    print_r($_GET);
    exit("empty");
}
```

**Console answer on page** returns "empty" and **not empty** array

```
Array
(
    [rate] => rating=1
)
empty
```

Comment: You just say it's "not correct". But what do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about the answer becoming incorrect. How are you checking whether it's correct or incorrect?

Comment: Do you have multiple `.rate_form` on the page? You're serializing all of them. I think you want `var rate_form = $(this).closest(".rate_form");`

Comment: @Barmar i have just one .rate_form. Try to explain: When GET is empty, php returns 'empty', but ajax prints 'not empty'.

Comment: `cache: false` adds an extra parameter, so `$_GET` is never empty.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` will never be empty when you use `cache: false`. This works by adding an extra `_=(timestamp)` parameter to the query string, so that the URL will always be different, in order to prevent it from being cached (this is called a "cachebuster"). As a result, `$_GET['_']` will always be set.

You should remove that element before checking.

```
unset($_GET['_']); // remove cachebuster
if (empty($_GET)) {
    echo "empty";
} else {
    echo "not empty";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not related to the problem. I completely got rid of "cache", but the situation has not changed. I even tried checking only one $ _GET argument for `empty()` (trying `isset()` also). 

**The result is the same as before:** in rate.php the answer is correct (depending on whether the request is empty or with arguments), and on the page with the form there is always only one answer: "empty". Moreover, even stranger, if you return the $ _GET array, then it returns correctly (when $ _GET is not empty, it returns "empty" and **not empty** array)

Comment: You're checking `$_GET['rating']`, but the name of the parameter is `rate`.

Comment: In `data: {
      "rate": rate
    }` the value of `$_GET['rate']` is the serialized form. You probably should just do `data: rate` so you don't add an extra level of wrapping.